# How to open url inside lsp-ui-doc popup childframe in browser

Tags: spacemacs, golang, lsp-ui

I am using `spacemacs` go layer with `lsp` as backend with `gopls`. How to open the link in the childframe of `lsp-ui-doc` in browser?